# Calculate spreadsheet row height

Tags: apache-poi

With Apache POI, is there a way to calculate row height given the cell style for a "default" cell in this row?

Empirically, I found out that row height for a row filled with cells containing text in Arial 10pt is 15. However, I would prefer a more deterministic aproach to get this done, instead of building a quick'n'dirty solution.

Comment: Row aitosize work for me, `cell.getRow().setHeight((short)0);` Here 0 for calculate autoheight.

Comment: Unforunately, autosize is not an option for me, because in one column there is some text which could be up to 2000 chars. Therefore I'm about to implement my own height-sizing routine, in which I'll need the "default" row height.